# Why code after Task.WhenAll executes before all tasks end?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Why does method `Redraw` executes before all tasks ended?

I have break point in both lines: `Redraw` and `_images.Add(image);` and breakpoint hits `Redraw` before `_images.Add(image);`

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var url in result)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        var image = await http.DownloadImagesAsync(url);
        _images.Add(image);
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Redraw();
```

Comment: `Task.Run`, not `Task.Factory.StartNew` (`Task.Run` has an overload which takes a `Func<Task>`; `Task.Factory.StartNew` doesn't, which means your `async ()` lambda is being turned into an `async void` method)

Comment: Because you create a fire and forget lambda to run in a new thread.

Comment: You're creating tasks that wrap tasks. The outer task just creates the inner task; that action is quick and finishes almost immediately. You're checking the outer tasks

Comment: Also you should not add to ordinary list from multiple threads.

Comment: You are wasting threads by using them to run async I/O operations. Add the Task from `http.DownloadImagesAsync` directly to `tasks`.

Comment: @GuruStron They're not. That code is adding tasks to the list synchronously.

Comment: You likely want `_images.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(result.Select(url => http.DownloadImagesAsync(url))));`

Comment: @itsme86 He's talking about the `_images` list

Comment: @itsme86 yes, got confused with `_images.Add(image)` =)

Comment: @canton7 in this case the async lambda is not actually converted to async void, because the `Task.Factory.StartNew` has an overload `StartNew<TResult>(Func<TResult>)`, and the `TResult` is resolved as `Task`. Hence it returns a `Task<Task>`. Async voids are created when async lambdas are passed to `Action` parameters.